# How do I mark values that exist in 2 different fields

Tags: ms-access

I'd like to mark values that exists in both the field "ID" and the field "NUMBER".
The value is not important (e.g. True/False or -1/0)

I have tried the following but that did not work.

`DESIRED OUTCOME: DLookUp("ID","Table1","NUMBER= ID")`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DESIRED OUTCOME: (DLookUp("[NUMBER]","[Table1]","[NUMBER] = " & [ID] & "") = [ID])
```